# gitlab 6.0.2 Jenkins CI services not showing

Tags: gitlab, jenkins-cli, gitlab-ci

I have a gitlab server version "Gitlab 6.0.2 10b0b8f". I want to connect "Jenkins CI" for build purpose. for this I am following - http://doc.gitlab.com/ee/integration/jenkins.html .But In a project services I am not able to see "Jenkins CI". Only I can See "Gitlab CI". Can you please help me. Any example will be appriciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Solved. Jenkins CI support is only included in the Enterprise version (EE). gitlab server version "Gitlab 6.0.2 10b0b8f" is not a enterprise edition. so it is not possible. Check 
https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/7525

Comment: Does this mean it won't be possible to trigger automatic builds in Jenkins CI on a Push event on Gitlab Community Edition (Version 8.1)?

Comment: Sorry for late. yes as per documentation.